# Loop counter & pointers

Tags: c, performance, pointers, loops

I'm writing a small specialized C99 library for graphs and I often get loops of the form:

```
for(int i = 0; i < graph->nvertices; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

I'm wondering if it's a good practice, especially in the case of tigh loop. At first I thought the compiler would be smart enough to look at 'graph->nvertices' only once instead of looking at it at every iteration, but it seems impossible as graph->nvertices could change inside the loop. Is is smarter and faster to write:

```
const int N = graph->nvertices;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

It seems faster as it doesn't need look at the pointer more than once, but it does require the creation of a new variable.

*Note: I guess this is the kind of situation where it's nice to be able to read a little assembly code to see what the compiler is actually doing, if someone has a nice reference I'm open to suggestions.*

Comment: Generally, I wouldn't even care and just do with the one that's a line less. It's trivial to add this if the loop in question becomes a hotspot and it turns out that this micro-optimization helps notably.

Comment: First, what should happen if `graph->nvertices` changes during the loop?  The second version may or may not be faster, but it is semantically different.

Comment: @David: Exactly, the second version actually states that the upper limit won't change.

Comment: Note that, assuming you don't actually modify it in the loop, whether the compiler will optimize out re-reading `graph-nvertices` depends mainly on (1) whether there are enough registers to keep it cached anyway, and (2) whether you make any use of `char` pointers or pointers of the same type as `nvertices` (which could alias it) in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using higher optimization settings, some compilers should be able to optimize that away for you. You can also iterate backwards, only initializing the counter with the expression:

```
for (int i = graph->nvertices; i >= 0; --i) 
  ..
```

However, you're going to wreak havoc on cache performance. I think the method you suggested is most straightforward, which lends itself to be clear to the compiler and to the next person reading your code.

Comment: It's an interesting idea (and avoid creating a variable) but why iterating backward would 'wreak havoc' on cache performance ?

Comment: Caches are designed with data locality in mind and usually assume forward-walking accesses. If you're walking backwards, you'll get much more cache misses than walking forwards. This is purely from intuition however, so please test and confirm on your own.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the cache on any modern processor couldn't handle backward iteration. Many compilers will optimize a forward counting loop into a backward counting loop since it requires one less register (to store `graph->nvertices`) and comparison with zero is typically faster than comparison with an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Also, to clarify on why this might cause cache misses: most processor have some automatic prefetching mechanism. If you make sequential accesses to memory, the prefetcher will attempt to cache memory it thinks you are about to hit, thus hiding the latency of compulsory cache misses. How well this actually works depends on how smart the prefetcher is. If it can't handle backward iteration, then yeah, you'll notice some cache misses.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to do these optimizations myself. Sometimes the compiler can infer that `nvertices` doesn't change along the whole loop, but what if you have call to other functions that *may* change the value? The compiler cannot infer it and may not optimize the code.

Also, the best way always is profiling your code to see the comparison between the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

i use this usually.

```
const int N = graph->nvertices;
int i = 0;
for(; i < N; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Why use **an extra line** (with absolutely zero gain, readability or performance or otherwise) to initialize the loop counter *and* leak it to a scope that shouldn't need it?

Comment: @deinan. most C programs do not use all the features from C99.

Comment: But C99 is a given the question, so answers shouldn't focus solely on other language versions (in the places where it makes a difference, e.g. here). (And personally, I consider not leaving the initialization part empty more readable even in C89.)

Comment: i dont have much experience with c, with some languages this is faster.

Comment: @viaria: interpreted languages?

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on your compiler, but most compilers will produce an assembly listing for you that you can study. Just make sure you list the release build.

However, if I was really concerned about every bit of performance, I might create the separate count variable as you suggest.

In the end, I doubt it would make a noticeable amount of difference.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a way to look at the assembler code. For this you can use the `objdump` program like this:

```
objdump -d executable
```

To filter out the main-function, use:

```
objdump -d executable | sed -n '/<main>/,/^$/p'
```

Comment: There's usually a compiler to simply output assembly instead of object/machine code (`-S` with GCC and Clang), which is more convenient and might give easier-to-read assembly (but won't include link-time optimizations, I assume).

Answer (score 0):

This seems a fairly easy thing to test, simply by looking at the output of the compiler.  Whole program optimization usually catches these low level optimizations.

On the other hand, I usually won't make these types of optimizations even if there is a slight increase in speed, since I find the first form easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for localizing the scope of the variable. The optimizer will then figure out all by itself:

```
for(size_t i = 0, n = graph->nvertices; i < n; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i dont know what optimezer is making it, but in every loop machine has to figure out this part -> graph->nvertices. do i know wrong.